# Why use parameter in CSS instead of just change name?

Tags: css, parameters

I have had some problems with new css not loading due to cache. To fix this I have previously just renamed the css file, liked this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styleV12.css"/>
```

This seem to work, but everywhere I read it says that you should use params instead. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css?v=1.2"/>
```

So I wonder why should I use params? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Makes no difference from the cache busting perspective, but with your way you have to keep renaming the file, versus just changing the query string parameter which lets you keep the same file name.

Comment: ah, that makes sense! Haha so easy when you say it. Thanks!

Comment: Adding to what @j08691 mentioned - if you are renaming the file constantly, you will lose any source control change history associated with it.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.